# Aptana Studio 3 External Server

Tags: php, local, aptana

I can't seem to get an external server working with Aptana Studio 3 on Windows. I am using XAMPP, and I set the Base URL to http://localhost and the Document Root to my htdocs folder in XAMPP, but it keeps saying Launch URL is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have configured the external server with the option "Use selected server" in "Run configurations". Apparently there is no way to get external servers running in Aptana Studio 3 this way (I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 using Apache and had the same problem).

Define your external server in "Use base URL" instead, don't forget to check "Append project name".

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my path was not correct. Also, rather than specifying the Server, I just set the Start URL to the page I want to debug. In my case the web server is IIS on Windows 7(64bit).